# Adding system properties in Spring MVC webapp

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, log4j2

I am using Hibernate 4.3.7.Final and Log4j2 in my Spring MVC webapp, published via Tomcat 7. All configuration is done via JavaConfig (i.e. there is no web.xml or other XML config files).

By default the Hibernate logging does not go through Log4j, for reasons explained in the [Apache wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/logging/Log4j2AndHibernate4). In order to resolve this I need to create a system setting as follows:

```
System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");
```

As my application is a webapp there is no Main thread, and as a result I an unsure where to put this `System.setProperty` call. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: which web container are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define this system property in context listener which is the first entry point as below:

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListenerExample implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e){
        System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");
    }
}
```

You could even define system property using spring as below:

```
<bean id="setupJBossLoggingProperty"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.SystemPropertyInitializer"
       p:keyName="org.jboss.logging.provider" p:defaultValue="slf4j"/>
```

And then you could say something like:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
     depends-on="setupJBossLoggingProperty">
 ...
```

So this means system property will be setted first and then hibernate bean is going to be initialised.

Comment: I tried adding the ContextListenerExample class to my project, but had to declare it as an abstract. However, when I run my MVC web app, I don't see the application ever reaching the methods within contextInitialized. Is there something else that needs to be added to the project? In my particular case, I'm setting the trustStore and keyStore properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some `WebApplicationInitializer` implementation to bootstrap your Spring application (which I assume you are since you have no web.xml) you could put it in `onStartup()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");
}
```